# When recalling the same piece of memory in different times, are the brain activities different?

Tags: neuroscience, neuroanatomy, memory

When we are thinking about the same piece of memory in multiple different times, would the corresponding brain activities always be the same? Or how similar/different can the corresponding brain activities be?

Answer (score 1):

The term for the brain activity that corresponds to an experience is "neural representation".

Neural representations "drift" over time.  From https://elifesciences.org/articles/51121:

> Similar ‘representational drift’ has been shown in other neocortical
> areas and hippocampus (Attardo et al., 2015; Ziv et al., 2013; Levy et
> al., 2019).

So that means that the brain activities corresponding to an experience can change over time.